メンテナンスのお知らせ：9月17日 (火) 6:00〜11:00 JST
Meta Stack Exchange に記載されている通り、ネットワークメンテナンスを予定しています。
メンテナンス期間：
2024年9月17日（火）6:00 ～ 11:00（日本時間）
今回のメンテナンスでは、データベースの移行作業が含まれます。この期間中、既にログインしているユーザーは通常通りアクセスできますが、メンテナンス開始時にログインしていないユーザーは、メールやパスワードを使用してログインすることができません。Google、GitHub、または Facebook でのログインが設定されている場合、それらを利用してアクセス可能です。
なお、新規ユーザーはメンテナンス中に新しいアカウントを登録することができません。ご不便をおかけしますが、ご理解のほどよろしくお願いいたします。
